# Catch action events from a JPanel component in a JFrame parent window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, custom-component, actionevent

How to catch action events from a `JPanel` component in a `JFrame` parent window in Java Swing?

I'm having a hard time trying to make a custom Component in Swing.

The idea I got is making a custom JPanel in Swing which contains some `JButton`, and catching the action events over those buttons in a JFrame parent window.

I would like to implement the method `addActionListener()` to my custom JPanel as if it were a button.

Do I have to extend from `JComponent` instead of `JPanel`?

I really appreciate your help and your time.

```
package pizzeria.interfaz;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

public class AplicacionCliente extends JFrame{

    public AplicacionCliente() {

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        PanelMenu panelmenu = new PanelMenu(); //PanelMenu extends JPanel and has my buttons


        JButton bot = new JButton("Prueba");        
        bot.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Botonazo!");

            }}); 


        contentPane.add(bot);
        contentPane.add(panelmenu, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, may works

```
public class AplicacionCliente extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

public AplicacionCliente() {

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setVisible(true);

    PanelMenu panelmenu = new PanelMenu(); //PanelMenu extends JPanel and has my buttons


    JButton bot = new JButton("Prueba");
    bot.addMouseListener(this);
    bot.setName("bot");

    contentPane.add(bot);
    contentPane.add(panelmenu, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getName().compareToIgnoreCase("bot")==0){
        System.out.println("Botonazo!!");
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

Comment: Hi scgr, let me try it. So I could get the pressed button name or tag and add some code for the behavior of the button, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can set the name of the button with `bot.setName("name")` and then check if the button pressed it the button you want using `getName()` from the event

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to catch the clicked button from the parent window.

Comment: With the last code, you can differentiate all posible buttons on the panel and manage differents behaviour of this buttons

Comment: There is something strange, but implementing MouseListener is not working because I can't detect when I click the button. I'm going to keep checking it. However I really appreciate yor help scgr. Thanks.

Comment: Very strange, I check the code personally and it works, I don't know what error is giving you